# Type not enforced in angular 2 template with typescript but enforce in ts code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am following [this official tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html)

Consider the following code snippet

`HTML`

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero.id)">
  <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}} 
</li>
```

`TS file`

```
selectedHero: Hero;

onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
  console.log(hero); // outputs 11 
  console.log(typeof hero); // outputs number
  this.selectedHero = hero;
}
```

onSelect takes in a `Hero` type and I expect that if a `Hero` type is not passed in, the browser will complain.

However no errors were raised. I can even assign a number type to `this.selectedHero`

Is template `types` simply not enforced?

Can someone explain to me where I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you assigning the number?

Comment: @echonax number is coming from `hero.id` in `onSelect(hero.id)`

Comment: Things like Closure, TypeScript, and so on, are facades on top of a language that has no notion of strict static types. This is a debate that I've had with several Google engineers; what is more practical and ultimately yields more stable code: practice controlling the language in its standard form, or try to add a control facade to deal with the language in a way that the language doesn't support and that is ultimately discarded when the code is run. I can show a number of ways to "accidentally" beat Closure type annotations, which is what got me thinking this way; is it really a good idea?

Comment: @TimConsolazio How would we ever get any useful language if we are not allowed to add higher-level concepts on top of a lower-level language? Wouldn't we all still be writing assembly?

Comment: Higher level concepts are one thing, but fundamentally altering the character of the language is another. Although programming languages more closely align, it has the same issues as say, speaking to somebody in japanese exclusively through a translation device. The listener may understand it and it might even do a good job, but the character and subtlety of the language, which is what makes it expressive in its own right, would be hamstrung. And some things just don't seem to translate. Over time I suspect you'll see more of a departure as TS becomes a language in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is only giving you compile-time errors, it has no control or validation of what is happening during execution of the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are not types in JavaScript, that's why browser is not reporting any error. TypeScript is checking types only before compiling the code to plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Since the assignment is on the html file, you will not see any errors but if you have made this inside the typescript (`ts`) file like:

```
constructor(){
  this.onSelect(1); //<-- this will give you an error that the method is expecting a Hero type but that you've given a number
}
```

you would be seeing errors.

So short answer to your question:
"*Is template types simply not enforced*?"; No they are not.